# Printing/writing a nested derived data type

Tags: fortran

I obtained the following module from a colleague. I am trying to make a program that returns the data in the derived data types. I do not have experience with derived data types. I tried the program TABLE (end of the file) but I was not able to get anything. How can I print or write the derived data type?

```
  C=======================================================================
  MODULE mod_AsosCommDates
  C=======================================================================

  IMPLICIT NONE

  INTEGER, PARAMETER :: NCommDates=2

  TYPE ASOSData
        CHARACTER (LEN=40) :: City
        CHARACTER (Len=60) :: Location
        CHARACTER (LEN=2)  :: State
        INTEGER            :: IWBAN
        CHARACTER (LEN=4)  :: INTCALL
        CHARACTER (LEN=3)  :: USACALL
        REAL               :: DDLAT
        REAL               :: DDLON
        CHARACTER (LEN=8)  :: COMMISDATE
        CHARACTER (LEN=3)  :: PUB
        CHARACTER (LEN=3)  :: SITETYPE
        REAL               :: ANEM_FEET
        REAL               :: ANEM_METERS
  END TYPE ASOSData

  TYPE (ASOSDATA), DIMENSION(NCommDates) :: ASOSCommDates

  CONTAINS

     SUBROUTINE InitAsosCommInfo (ASOSCommDates)

     TYPE (ASOSDATA), DIMENSION(NCommDates) :: ASOSCommDates

  ASOSCommDates(1) = ASOSDATA("ANCHORAGE","LAKE HOOD SEAPLANE BASE",
 &  "AK",26491,"PALH","LHD",61.17,-149.96,"19980122","NO","FAA",
 &  33.00,10.05)
  ASOSCommDates(2) = ASOSDATA("ANCHORAGE","MERRILL FIELD AIRPORT",
 &  "AK",26409,"PAMR","MRI",61.21,-149.85,"19971015","NO","FAA",
 &  16.00,4.87)

         END SUBROUTINE InitAsosCommInfo

  END MODULE mod_AsosCommDates

  PROGRAM TABLE
  USE mod_AsosCommDates
  CALL InitAsosCommInfo(ASOSCommDates)
  PRINT *,ASOSCommDates(1)%ASOSData%City
  END PROGRAM TABLE
```

**Post edited May 25, 2016 at 10:54 am EST**
Example originally posted had different errors to those associated with the question of this post.

`NCommDates` changed from `NCommDates=886` to `NCommDates=2`
CALL line changed from `CALL InitAsosCommInfo` to `CALL InitAsosCommInfo(ASOSCommDates)`

Error during compilation is:

```
$ gfortran 2.for
2.for:48.39:

      PRINT *,ASOSCommDates(1)%ASOSData%City
                    1 Error: 'asosdata' at (1) is not a member of the 'asosdata' structure
```

Comment: It is most strange indeed that you are not getting anything. I am actually getting compile time error messages. What does "not anything" mean for you?

Comment: The compilation problem is because my CALL statement was not correct. Initially it was `CALL InitAsosCommInfo`.
It was edited to `CALL InitAsosCommInfo(ASOSCommDates)`. However my initial question was answered by Alexander Vogt comment.

Comment: The point is you should always include the error messages in your posts. Anyway, be sure to also try just `PRINT *,ASOSCommDates(1)`.

Comment: As @VladimirF suggest `PRINT *,ASOSCommDates(1)` will print the entire record. The example posted was edited for clarity.

Answer (score 2):

Although the Fortran Standard specifies that you can write type-bound procedures for I/O, many compilers don't support this yet. So the simplest solution would be to print the derived type component-wise.

However, in your code there is no need to specify the type when accessing the components:

```
PRINT *,ASOSCommDates(1)%City
```

... and similarly for the other components.

Comment: The derived type doesn't contain any private, pointer or allocatable components, so in an input or output list an object of the type is automatically expanded to a list of its components.